# How to generat errors from normal distribution in R

Tags: r

can you help me with this question? I don't know how to create errors

Randomly generate 500 errors, ui, from the Normal distribution whose mean
is 0 and variance is 36. Is the sample average of the ui exactly zero? Why or why not?
What is the sample standard deviation of the ui?

Comment: have a look at `?rnorm`. If you are still stuck please edit your question with your attempts explaining what you dont understand

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by another respondent, you can use the `rnorm()` function to generate random draws from a normal distribution. An example: https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/languages/R/functions/rnorm

Regarding the second part of your question, you could look at the Central Limit Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem). The sample mean should follow a normal distribution with the same mean you are using to generate the random values. Its  standard deviation should equal `sigma/sqrt(n)`, where `sigma` is the standard deviation you are using to generate the random values and `n` is the number of random values (500 in this case).